# I have yml file content and show content in text box, key and values are color show in different color?

Tags: reactjs

swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: os-config-drive-v2.1
  version: Unknown
consumes:
- application/json
produces:
- application/json
paths:
  "/v2.1/servers/{server_id}":
    get:
      operationId: returnserver
      summary: Show server details
      description: |
        Shows details for a specified server.
      produces:
      - application/json
      responses:
        '200':
          description: 200 response